# Where is the error in the following proof that $f\colon[-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)= \cos(x)$ is not a contraction.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Where is the error in the following proof that  $f\colon[-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)= \cos(x)$ is not a contraction.

We have that $f'(x) = -\sin(x)$ and so for all $x \in [-1,1],  |f'(x)| \leq 1$. So F is Lipschitz continuous with $K = 1$. Since $K$ is not less than 1, $f$ is not a contraction.

Comment: You forgot to use the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[-1, 1]$ – how large can $|f'(x)|$ be *on that interval?*

Comment: You proved $f$ was $1$-Lipschitz, but not that $f$ was not $c$-Lipschitz for any $c<1$. (I/e/, you showed an *upper bound* on the Lipschitz constant, but... that upper bound is not tight)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

> So $F$ is Lipschitz continuous with $K=1$. Since $K$ is not less than $1$, f is not a contraction.

Note that while you proved that $K=1$ works, you did not prove that this is the best which works.

To inderstand the issue look at $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$. You have that $|f'(x)|<1000$ and hence $f$ is 1000-Lipschitz continuous. But this does not prove that $f$ is not a contraction, actually it is easy to see that $f$ is **also** $\frac{1}{2}$-Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ |f'(x)|=1$$ where $$ x=2k\pi \pm \pi/2$$

Since the domain is $[-1,1]$  we have $$ |f'(x)|<1$$   on the domain.